# E[max(X-K), 0] where K is a constant, and X is normally dist. with mean = mu and variance = sigma^2

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a simple question. Is it not possible to simply say that this is equal to max(E(X)-K, 0). So the only thing I need to do is calculate E(X)?

Comment: Your question is poorly worded and contains several mistakes. Can you read it again carefully and fix the mistakes?

Comment: No, in general $E(\max(X-K,0))\neq \max(E(X)-K,0)$, and there seems to be no reason to expect this anyway. Use the *definitions* and *law of unconscious statistician*: $E(g(X))=\int g(x) f_X(x) dx$ where $g(x)=\max\{x-K,0\}$ and $f_X$ is the PDF of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Let $\varphi$ denote the density of $X$. Then,
\begin{multline*}
\mathbb{E}\left[\max(X-K,0)\right]
=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\max(x-K,0)\varphi(x)dx
=\int_{K}^{\infty}\left(x-K\right)\varphi(x)dx\\
=\int_{K}^{\infty}x\varphi(x) - K \int_{K}^{\infty}\varphi(x)dx
\end{multline*}